# Input placeholder value inexplicably moves to its parent element

Tags: vue.js

I'm currently learning Vue3 and have run into a strange issue I can't seem to find a solution for.

I have this simple CoordinateField component, which is essentially just a text input field. I pass the id and placeholder values in as props. However, in the output, for some reason the placeholder value moves from the input field to its parent div element, thus obviously not showing up in the field. I've also tried wrapping placeholder in [[ ]] but that didn't help.

Here is my code and an example:

```
<template>
    <div class="text-field">
        <input type="text" :id="id" class="text-field__input" :placeholder="placeholderText" />
        <label :for="id" class="text-field__label"></label>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        id: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        placeholderText: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

The component is called inside other components simply like this:

```
<CoordinateField id="lat" placeholder="Latitude" />
<CoordinateField id="lng" placeholder="Longitude" />
```

[A screenshot of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CJU9.png)

Comment: There’s a typo in your prop definition or prop usage. You defined the prop as `placeholderText` but is using `placeholder` attribute in the template. Just do this in your template: `<CoordinateField id="lat" placeholder-text="Latitude" />`

Comment: OH! That makes perfect sense, my bad. It works now, thank you!
As a sidenote, I'm still curious about how it ended up on the parent element, and after fiddling around, it seems any additional attributes (which aren't props or otherwise defined in your component) you add to a component call will simply get appended to the first element in it?

Comment: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-attrs.html#attribute-inheritance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you have defined the prop `placeholderText` but using attribute `placeholder`.
As this attribute are not recognized as prop it inherit as attribute.

To prevent attribute inheritance you can use `inheritAttrs: false` and bind attributes to target elements using `v-bind="$attrs"`

```
<template>
    <div class="text-field">
        <input type="text" class="text-field__input" v-bind="$attrs" />
        <label :for="id" class="text-field__label"></label>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    inheritAttrs: false,
}
</script>
```

More about non-prop attributes:
https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-attrs.html#attribute-inheritance